# pandas modifying sections then recombining

Tags: python, pandas

I have been on modifying an excel document with Pandas. I only need to work with small sections at a time, and breaking each into a separate DataFrame and then recombining back into the whole after modifying seems like the best solution. Is this feasible? I've tried a couple options with merge() and concat() but they don't seem to give me the results I am looking for.

As previously stated, I've tried using the merge() function to recombine them back together with the larger table I just got a memory error, and when I tested it with smaller dataframes, rows weren't maintained.

here's an small scale example of what I am looking to do:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,5,6],'B':[3,10,11,13,324],'C':[64,'','' ,'','' ],'D':[32,45,67,80,100]})#example df
print(df1)
df2= df1[['B','C']]#section taken
df2.at[2,'B'] = 1#modify area
print(df2)
df1 = df1.merge(df2)#merge dataframes
print(df1)
```

output:

```py
   A    B   C    D
0  1    3  64   32
1  2   10       45
2  3   11       67
3  5   13       80
4  6  324      100
     B   C
0    3  64
1   10    
2    1    
3   13    
4  324    
   A    B   C    D
0  1    3  64   32
1  2   10       45
2  5   13       80
3  6  324      100
```

what I would like to see

```py
   A    B   C    D
0  1    3  64   32
1  2   10       45
2  3   11       67
3  5   13       80
4  6  324      100
     B   C
0    3  64
1   10    
2    1    
3   13    
4  324    
   A    B   C    D
0  1    3  64   32
1  2   10       45
2  3    1       67
3  5   13       80
4  6  324      100
```

as I said before,in my actual code I just get a memoryerror if I try this due to the size of the dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for merging here, you can just re-assign back the values from `df2` into `df1`:

```
...
df1.loc[df2.index, df2.columns] = df2 #recover changes into original dataframe
print(df1)
```

giving as expected:

```
   A    B   C    D
0  1    3  64   32
1  2   10       45
2  3    1       67
3  5   13       80
4  6  324      100
```

---

`df1.update(df2)` gives same result (thanks to Quang Hoang for the precision)

Comment: one thing to note, if you've changed the index, you need to reset it before you update